# Nodejs - Axios - Timeouts lead to memory leak

Tags: node.js, http, axios

I'm running an app which basically:

Receives a request through Express.js
Send multiples requests to various endpoints
Once those endpoints responses, we compute a response and send it to the client.
I'm using Axios Instances per endpoints to send the requests.

```
const axios = require('axios');

const Agent = require('agentkeepalive');

const { HttpsAgent } = Agent;

const httpKeepAliveAgent = new Agent({
  maxSockets: 100,
  maxFreeSockets: 10,
  timeout: 60000, // active socket keepalive for 60 seconds
  freeSocketTimeout: 30000, // free socket keepalive for 30 seconds
});

const httpsKeepAliveAgent = new HttpsAgent({
  maxSockets: 100,
  maxFreeSockets: 10,
  timeout: 60000, // active socket keepalive for 60 seconds
  freeSocketTimeout: 30000, // free socket keepalive for 30 seconds
});

const createAxiosInstance = () => axios.create({
  httpAgent: httpKeepAliveAgent,
  httpsAgent: httpsKeepAliveAgent,
  maxRedirects: 10,
});
```

I send requests to third party endpoint using the following

```
const fakeServer = require('../test/fake-server');
const logger = require('../utils/logger');

const { LOG_VERBOSE } = process.env;

// let promiseCount = 0;

module.exports = async (axiosInstance, ssp, payload, endpoint, method, timeout, headers) => {
  const cmd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? fakeServer : axiosInstance;
  const start = Date.now();
  const config = {
    ssp,
    url: endpoint,
    method,
    timeout,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
    data: payload,
  };
  if (headers !== undefined && typeof headers === 'object') {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-return-assign
    Object.keys(headers).forEach((key) => config.headers[key] = headers[key]);
  }
  try {
    const response = await cmd(config);
    return {
      ssp,
      uri: config.url,
      requestbody: payload,
      requestheaders: config.headers,
      responsebody: response.data,
      status: response.status,
      responsetimemillis: Date.now() - start,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    if (LOG_VERBOSE === 'true') logger.error(`Error on ${ssp} call: ${error.message}`);
    let responsebody;
    let status;
    if (error.response === undefined) {
      responsebody = error.code;
      status = error.code;
    } else {
      responsebody = error.response.data ? error.response.data : error.message;
      status = error.response.status;
    }
    return {
      ssp,
      uri: config.url,
      requestbody: payload,
      requestheaders: config.header,
      responsebody,
      status,
      responsetimemillis: Date.now() - start,
    };
  }
};
```

The issues is that when I get timeouts or 400 error, there might happen some memory leaks, I can't get a successful linked connection, and so at the end the app crashes...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2783

maxRedirects may be causing this issue, try setting lower redirects or 0, as the resolved issue suggests.